Angular 17 routes
Having some issues creating proper route for a detailed user page, I have the following in my new app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'login',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'admin',
      component: AdminLayoutComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      data: {
        expectedRole: ['admin']
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: 'dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: AdminDashboardComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        },
        {
          path: 'users',
          component:AdminUsersComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        },
        {
          path: 'users/add',
          component:UserAddComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        },
        //{
        //  path: 'users/edit/:id',
        //  component:UserEditComponent,
        //  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        //},
        ]
      }
    ];

as soon as I uncomment the edit the UserEditComponent, I get routed back to login even though the route on the URL bar stays as 'http://localhost:4200/admin/users' and can't login again, all the console throws is the following error
mime.js:25 Uncaught 
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Mime.define (mime.js:25:7)
    at node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js (mime.js:87:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=d75b31b0:41:50)
    at node_modules/send/index.js (index.js:24:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=d75b31b0:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/utils.js (utils.js:20:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=d75b31b0:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/application.js (application.js:24:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=d75b31b0:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:18:13)

and also a bunch of warnings
browser-external:path:9 Module "path" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "path.dirname" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.

has anyone faced this kind of issue with the new Angular routes?

I imagine you have a module that declare your AdminUsersComponent, UserAddComponent and ... Are you sure you add in the module the UserEditComponent?

on Angular 17 by defaults all the components are standalone and there is no app.module.ts to declare them, or an admin.module either. Adding a user works fine in the UserAddComponent, the problem is the UserEdit

I saw this question posted but none of the answers were helping, in my particular case, an import on the UserEditComponent was causing this error, I did not realize the Router import was not coming from @angular/router and instead
import { Router } from 'express';

this import was causing issues, hope this helps anyone facing the issue, check your component imports :)
